# Create multidimensional array from one mysql table

Tags: json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate nested json data like in this example from one mysql table.

```
var data = {
"62" : {
    "section" : "bodyImage",
    "img" : "imageurl/image62.png",
    "label" : "blue",
    "price" : "100"
},
"63" : {
    "section" : "bodyImage",
    "img" : "imageurl/image63.png",
    "label" : "red",
    "price" : "120"
}
}
```

62 and 63 are from the row data_id in the following table:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-------+---------+
| data_id   | section    | img             | label | price   | 
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-------+----------
| 62        | bodyImage  | imagpath/image62.png    |  blue | 100     |
| 63        | bodyImage  | imagpath/image62.png    |  red  | 120     | 
+-----------+------------+-------------------------+-------+---------

+
```

This is the php file with the query:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT data_id, section, img, label, price FROM table WHERE active != 'no'");

$data = array();

while($row=@mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

$data[] = array (

    'section' => $row['sub_section'],
    'img' => $row['big_image'],
    'label' => $row['label_client_en'],
    'price' => $row['price']

);

}
echo json_encode( $data );
```

I cannot get it working. Please help me with the right syntax for the multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot json_encode "sub arrays" directly on the main array

You must do json_encode for each array in your while:

```
$data[] = json_encode(array (

'section' => $row['sub_section'],
'img' => $row['big_image'],
'label' => $row['label_client_en'],
'price' => $row['price']
));
```

And then you must also encode the main array as you already do.